# How to deploy react route 4 on IIS

Tags: reactjs, iis, react-router-v4

I have a react application with the following files and folders:

```
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── someCssFile.css
│   ├── js 
│   │   └── someJsFile.js
├── index.html
├── web.config
```

The web.config file is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <!-- This part is responsible for URL rewrites -->
        <rewrite>
         <rules>
             <rule name="DynamicContent">
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
       </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And the index.html file is as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="/static/css/main.8833e8af.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.8f22fc15.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have also installed the [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). But when deploying the app on the ISS, it does not work!

Could you please help me with the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your action url needs to be a fully qualified url. E.g.

`<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/index.html"/>`

`{HTTP_HOST}` is replaced by IIS with the actual hostname in the request. You may want to hardcode your actual domain if you have several domains/ redirects pointing at the same site.